# How to update a document with dynamic variable and nested objects in Mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I have documents, each with the following structure:

```
  {
   ...
   "Lessons": [],
   "Students": { 
      "Monday": {
      },
      "Tuesday": {
      },
      ...
    },
   "CampYear": "aprs22",
  }
```

What I'm after is to dynamically insert data into one of the day objects ("Monday", etc). I have the day coming in dynamically as well as a name and times. So, what the document would look like after the dynamic insert using "Monday", "PHOEBE SMITH", "1:00" and "2:00" would be:

```
  {
   ...
   "Lessons": [],
   "Students": { 
      "Monday": {
        "PHEOBE SMITH": ["1:00", "2:00"]
      },
      "Tuesday": {
      },
      ...
    },
   "CampYear": "aprs22",
  }
```

I thought of trying something like:

```
  scheduleCamper(camper, time1, time2, day) {
    Programs.update({ _id: targetTeacherId }, { $set: { 'Students[day]': { camper: [time1, time2]}} });
```

But this is wrong. Not sure how to handle this insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

```
const modifier = {};
modifier.Students[day] = { [camper]: [time1, time2]};
Programs.update({ _id: targetTeacherId }, { $set: modifier });
```

or:

```
Programs.update({ _id: targetTeacherId }, { $set: {
  [`Students.${day}`]: { [camper]: [time1, time2]}
}});
```

Comment: Just a correction on your second option: 'camper' had to be [`${camper}`], with backticks (can't get them to show in comments for some reason).

Comment: Great! How would one tackle it if there were existing key/value pairs inside the Monday object and just wanted to add the new key/value pair to the existing ones?

Comment: I answered my own question :) { $set: { [`Students.${day}.${camper}`]: [time, "55:00"] } }